# MVC 4 Oauth Client using SAML

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, saml-2.0

I have an MVC 4 application that uses several custom oauth clients (OpenIdClient, OAuth2Client and OAuthClient) to authenticate my user (google, linkedIn, facebook...). Now, I'd like to add a new 
external login that uses SAML 2.0 but I'd like to register it as any other external logins in my app.

So my question is (and apologies if it's obvious!), is it a wrong approach to implement a custom OAuth 2 or OpenOAuth Client that will basically just be a wrapper for the SAML process so it's transparent for my app? If not, is there any code sample I could you have a look at?

Any guidance would be very much appreciated!
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you can move to the Owin-based OAuth modules that are used by MVC5, you can use the [Kentor.AuthServices owin middleware](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Kentor.AuthServices.Owin/) together with other external login sources.

*Disclaimer: I'm the author of the Kentor.AuthServices library*